# how to detect user mouse scroll up event but not really trigger window scroll?

Tags: javascript, css

I try to do some page transition like this web. 
https://www.lytic.tech/ .

But I cannot figure out how to detect the mouse "scroll event" but not really trigger window scrolling, especially hide the scrollbar.

I try to set body `overflow: hidden` and try to set my container to `overflow: auto` to scroll only inside my container.
But it seems to block all the scrolling event.

Comment: I think you will find the answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: I try the disable scrolling solution but it's not disable the scrolling. :/ 
And also I not only want to disable scrolling, but also detect the event.
So I think it's not duplicated. 
Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You should be able to modify the code in the link I sent to trigger another function, e.g.  window.onwheel = (e) => {e.preventDefault; console.log('scroll attempted')}

Comment: I would like to stop div element to scroll. is that possible ?

Comment: 鄭元傑, you should ask a new question for that and include a copy of the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Add this css. I hope it will helps you.

```
html, body{
    height: 99%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 17px; 
    box-sizing: content-box; 
}
```